# White Bands Around Kivy Images

Tags: python, image, kivy

I'm pulling in images from an external website and displaying each in order in a fixed size box. The settings stretch the images to fill the constraints of the box, but the aspect ratio is kept. Because the images don't always match the aspect ratio of the box, I get white bands around the images. I can't figure out how to get rid of the white bands. I tried canvas.before with Color to try to color the box black, but it didn't work.

The images (and associated information) are pushed from Python:

```
class TheBox(FloatLayout):
    def update(self, *args):
        ..
        ..
        if (total_count % 2) == 0: 
            if which_petL < quantity:
                which_petL += 1
            else:
                which_petL = 0

            self.ids.PetL_photo.source = str(Lphoto)
```

The kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}         
            AsyncImage:
                id: PetL_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
            ..
            ..
```

And the result:

http://cselman.com/20160209_093304.mp4

Any help?

canvas.before attempts:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}         
            AsyncImage:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: (0, 0, 0)
                id: PetL_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
```

And...

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TheBox>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 0, 0)
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}         
            AsyncImage:
                id: PetL_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
```

And...

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: (0, 0, 0)      
            AsyncImage:
                id: PetL_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
```

Comment: can you show the `canvas.before` part that didn't work? Also, the Facebook link doesn't work for me (maybe b/c I'm not on FB)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're drawing on your canvas when using canvas.before. Try adding a Rectangle with size and pos set to self.size and self.pos.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a rectangle is what I was missing.

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}
            AsyncImage:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: (0, 0, 0)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                id: PetL_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
```